# Loop with if else and next R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

I am combining a loop with if else and next in R.

In order to reproduce my problem in its complexity, I cannot provide a minimum example but a big piece of code. The aim is to fill the list `df` with `min`, `max`, `50percentile` in the columns `rmse_1` and `rmse_2`.

You need to change the path according to your desired path at the positions marked with `# !!! change path`. If you changed the paths you can run the code:

```
# create lists
mse_samp <- list("mse_A" = list("P10" = data.frame(number = seq(1,3,1), 
                                                   mse_1 = c(2.5, 4.6, 7.8), 
                                                   mse_2 = c(6.7, 8.9, 4.1)), 
                                "P30" = data.frame(number = seq(1,3,1), 
                                                   mse_1 = c(22.5, 74.6, 97.8), 
                                                   mse_2 = c(56.7, 78.9, 14.1))),

                 "mse_B" = list("P10" = data.frame(number = seq(1,3,1), 
                                                   mse_1 = c(122.5, 124.6, 127.8), 
                                                   mse_2 = c(126.7, 128.9, 124.1)), 
                                "P30" = data.frame(number = seq(1,3,1), 
                                                   mse_1 = c(3422.5, 3474.6, 3497.8), 
                                                   mse_2 = c(3456.7, 3478.9, 3414.1))))
# !!! change path
save(mse_samp, 
     file="H:\\R\\Forum_data\\dat1.RData")

mse_samp <- list("mse_A" = list("P70" = data.frame(number = seq(1,3,1), 
                                                   mse_1 = c(22.2, 77.6, 97.8, 21.2, 73.9), 
                                                   mse_2 = c(26.7, 78.9, 17.1, 23.2, 82.2)),
                                "P80" = data.frame(number = seq(1,3,1), 
                                                   mse_1 = c(1022.2, 3077.6, 9097.8, 1221.2, 7373.9), 
                                                   mse_2 = c(7626.7, 2278.9, 7317.1, 7623.2, 8982.2))),
                 "mse_B" = list("P70" = data.frame(number = seq(1,3,1), 
                                                   mse_1 = c(3722.2, 3777.6, 3797.8), 
                                                   mse_2 = c(3726.7, 3778.9, 3717.1)),
                                "P80" = data.frame(number = seq(1,3,1), 
                                                   mse_1 = c(1022.2, 3077.6, 9097.8), 
                                                   mse_2 = c(7626.7, 2278.9, 7317.1))))

save(mse_samp, 
     file="H:\\R\\Forum_data\\dat2.RData")

# create table for min max for different perc and runs for each paramter (loop)
n_measure <- 3 # number of different measures
npr1 <- 2 # number of different percs run1
npr2 <- 2 # number of different percs run2


targets <- c("A",  "B")

for (i in 1:length(targets)) {
  df <- data.frame(run = c(rep("run1", n_measure * npr1),
                           rep("run2", n_measure * npr2)),

                   perc_train = c(rep(c(0.1, 0.3), times = 1, each = n_measure), # percs run 1
                                  rep(c(0.7, 0.8), times = 1, each = n_measure)), # percs run 2

                   measure = c(rep(c("min", "max", "50percentile"),
                                   times = npr1 + npr2, each = 1)),

                   rmse_1 = rep(NA,  n_measure * (npr1 + npr2)),
                   rmse_2 = rep(NA,  n_measure * (npr1 + npr2))
  )

  assign(paste0('df_', targets[i]), df)

}

df <- list("A" = df_A,  "B" = df_B)

# convert column which are factors to characters
for (i in 1:length(targets)) {

  df[[i]][sapply(df[[i]], is.factor)] <- lapply(df[[i]][sapply(df[[i]], is.factor)], 
                                                as.character)
}

rm(list = c("df_A", "df_B", "df_C"))
# !!! change path
path <- c("H:\\R\\Forum_data\\dat1.RData", # run1
# !!! change path          
          "H:\\R\\Forum_data\\dat2.RData") # run2

percs_names <- c("P10", "P30", "P70", "P80")
percs <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8)
targets <- c("A", "B")
run_name <- c("run1", "run2")
measure_name <- c("min", "max", "50percentile")
fill_names <- c("rmse_min_1", "rmse_min_2", "rmse_max_1", "rmse_max_2", 
                "percentile_50_1", "percentile_50_2")
var_name <- c("rmse_1", "rmse_2")
a_or_b <- c("a","b")


# read in data
for (i in 1:length(path)) {
  load(path[i])

  dat <- mse_samp


  for (j in 1:length(targets)) {
    for (k in 1:length(percs_names)) {
      # if statement
      if(percs_names[k] == names(dat[[j]][k])){

        dat1 <- dat[[paste0("mse_", targets[j])]][k][[1]]
        rmse_min_1 <- sqrt(min(dat1$mse_1))
        rmse_min_2 <- sqrt(min(dat1$mse_2))
        rmse_max_1 <- sqrt(max(dat1$mse_1))
        rmse_max_2 <- sqrt(max(dat1$mse_2))
        percentile_50_1 <- quantile(sqrt(dat1$mse_1), probs = 0.5)
        percentile_50_2 <- quantile(sqrt(dat1$mse_2), probs = 0.5)


        for (fi in 1:length(fill_names)) {    
        for (m in 1:length(measure_name)) {


          a <- which(df[[targets[j]]]$run == run_name[i] & 
                       df[[targets[j]]]$measure == measure_name[m] & 
                       df[[targets[j]]]$perc_train == percs[k] &
                       is.na(df[[targets[j]]]$rmse_1)
          )
          b <- which(df[[targets[j]]]$run == run_name[i] & 
                       df[[targets[j]]]$measure == measure_name[m] & 
                       df[[targets[j]]]$perc_train == percs[k] &
                       is.na(df[[targets[j]]]$rmse_2)
          )

          for (v in 1:length(var_name)) {


          df[[targets[j]]][eval(parse(text = a_or_b[v])), which(names(df[[targets[j]]]) == var_name[v])] <- eval(parse(text = fill_names[fi]))

        }

            }

          }



      }
      else { next }
    }
  }
}
```

**1. issue**  After running the code, the following error message occurs:

```
 Error in if (percs_names[k] == names(dat[[j]][k])) { : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I guess the error is probably caused by the `if else`statement. How can I run the code without the error?

**2. issue** Currently only rows for `run1` are filled. The `rmse_1` an `rmse_2` are filled with the same values in rows `min`, `max`, `50percentile`. They should be different. How can I fill the other runs and fill the rows correctly? In the end there should be no `NA` left.

Comment: "I cannot provide a minimum example but a big piece of code" There are definitely ways you can scale this back to its essence. For example, do you need so many list items, each with so many data frames, in order to illustrate the problem? It's really difficult to read through all this and know what's going on. Additionally, I think a lot of people will be reluctant to run code that requires them saving output to disk.

Comment: If your issue is just a simple true/false comparison in an if statement, you could find a way to set up something similar, isolating that problem with a whole lot less detail

Comment: If I dont post it like this, then people could try to use lappy or something like this, but I would like to work with the for loops. I posted minimum examples, but people come up with simple solutions which I cannot use for my problem... I thought it would be easier to mark the paths as people would find it more faster to insert their path. I don#t know if the problem is only caused by the if statement. maybe it's somewhere else. Thats why I am posting such a big code.

Comment: In debugging, you take things step by step. That might mean that you post one question for one problem, fix it, then find another problem to fix. That's okay. This *specific* problem looks like it's just checking values in a vector against the names of a nested list of lists. Figure out an example that doesn't need to be 197 lines of code, edit the question, and stress that you only want loop-based solutions

Comment: I'm still a beginner in R, and I just cannot figure out what exactly is causing the problem in my code.

Comment: Trying to simplify your problem to its essence is another way to improve your own skills while attempting to solve your problem at the same time. Furthermore, you make it simpler for others in stackoverflow to help you. I tell you this by own experience (sometimes you feel overwhelmed by the effort you've made so far, so that simplyfing looks difficult at the moment, but believe me, it's worth it!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you insist on using `for`-loops here is a solution to you problem with `map` (similiar to lapply) and some `tidyverse`-magic.

I have one assumption: All datasets your working on are stored in a list, called `data_runs_list`. An example is given at the end of the answer in the **Data**-section (using your example data).

So lets first bring this nested structure in a more readable format:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

data_runs_df <-
  map(data_runs_list, ~ map(.x, bind_rows, .id = "perc") %>% 
        bind_rows(.id = "target")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "run")

data_runs_df
# A tibble: 24 x 6
#  run   target perc  number  mse_1  mse_2
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 run1  mse_A  P10        1    2.5    6.7
# 2 run1  mse_A  P10        2    4.6    8.9
# 3 run1  mse_A  P10        3    7.8    4.1
# 4 run1  mse_A  P30        1   22.5   56.7
# 5 run1  mse_A  P30        2   74.6   78.9
# 6 run1  mse_A  P30        3   97.8   14.1
# 7 run1  mse_B  P10        1  122.   127. 
# 8 run1  mse_B  P10        2  125.   129. 
# 9 run1  mse_B  P10        3  128.   124. 
# 10 run1  mse_B  P30        1 3422.  3457. 
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

To better understand, what `bind_rows()` does, only take the first entry of the first entry of list and see what happens:

```
bind_rows(data_runs_list[[1]][[1]], .id = "perc")
#   perc number mse_1 mse_2
# 1  P10      1   2.5   6.7
# 2  P10      2   4.6   8.9
# 3  P10      3   7.8   4.1
# 4  P30      1  22.5  56.7
# 5  P30      2  74.6  78.9
# 6  P30      3  97.8  14.1
```

The two dataframes are stacked together and the id-column `perc` preserves the original list name. `map` then applies to each level of the list `bind_row` one after another, on each level with a different id-column.

So this is something to work with nicely. You want to have `min`, `max` and 50%-quantile (i.e. the `median`) of for each run, percentage, target and seperately for the two measurements `mse_1` and `mse_2`. `group_by` is perfect for this in combindation with `summarize`. To better handle the two different measurements, first convert the data to a long format. If you have more measurements you can just specify them at the end of the `gather`-call:

```
data_runs_df <- data_runs_df %>% 
  gather(mse, value, mse_1, mse_2)

data_runs_df 
# A tibble: 48 x 6
#   run   target perc  number mse    value
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1  run1  mse_A  P10        1 mse_1    2.5
# 2  run1  mse_A  P10        2 mse_1    4.6
# 3  run1  mse_A  P10        3 mse_1    7.8
# 4  run1  mse_A  P30        1 mse_1   22.5
# 5  run1  mse_A  P30        2 mse_1   74.6
# 6  run1  mse_A  P30        3 mse_1   97.8
# 7  run1  mse_B  P10        1 mse_1  122. 
# 8  run1  mse_B  P10        2 mse_1  125. 
# 9  run1  mse_B  P10        3 mse_1  128. 
# 10 run1  mse_B  P30        1 mse_1 3422. 
# ... with 38 more rows
```

Now, before the measurements are calculated, we rename the target and mse column quick and then use the `group_by` in combindation with `summarize`:

```
data_info <- data_runs_df %>% 
  mutate(mse = str_c("r", mse), 
         target = str_remove(target, "mse_")) %>% 
  group_by(run, target, perc, mse) %>% 
  summarize(min = min(sqrt(value)), 
            max = max(sqrt(value)), 
            median = median(sqrt(value))) 

data_info
# A tibble: 16 x 7
# Groups:   run, target, perc [?]
#   run   target perc  mse      min   max median
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  run1  A      P10   rmse_1  1.58  2.79   2.14
# 2  run1  A      P10   rmse_2  2.02  2.98   2.59
# 3  run1  A      P30   rmse_1  4.74  9.89   8.64
# 4  run1  A      P30   rmse_2  3.75  8.88   7.53
# 5  run1  B      P10   rmse_1 11.1  11.3   11.2 
# 6  run1  B      P10   rmse_2 11.1  11.4   11.3 
# 7  run1  B      P30   rmse_1 58.5  59.1   58.9 
# 8  run1  B      P30   rmse_2 58.4  59.0   58.8 
# 9  run2  A      P70   rmse_1  4.71  9.89   8.81
# 10 run2  A      P70   rmse_2  4.14  8.88   5.17
# 11 run2  A      P80   rmse_1 32.0  95.4   55.5 
# 12 run2  A      P80   rmse_2 47.7  87.3   85.5 
# 13 run2  B      P70   rmse_1 61.0  61.6   61.5 
# 14 run2  B      P70   rmse_2 61.0  61.5   61.0 
# 15 run2  B      P80   rmse_1 32.0  95.4   55.5 
# 16 run2  B      P80   rmse_2 47.7  87.3   85.5
```

Now one last step to get everything it the exact shap you wanted to have it we need `gather` and its counterpart `spread`:

```
data_info <- data_info %>% 
  gather(measure, value, min, max, median) %>% 
  spread(mse, value) 

data_info 
# A tibble: 24 x 6
# Groups:   run, target, perc [8]
#   run   target perc  measure rmse_1 rmse_2
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1  run1  A      P10   max       2.79   2.98
# 2  run1  A      P10   median    2.14   2.59
# 3  run1  A      P10   min       1.58   2.02
# 4  run1  A      P30   max       9.89   8.88
# 5  run1  A      P30   median    8.64   7.53
# 6  run1  A      P30   min       4.74   3.75
# 7  run1  B      P10   max      11.3   11.4 
# 8  run1  B      P10   median   11.2   11.3 
# 9  run1  B      P10   min      11.1   11.1 
# 10 run1  B      P30   max      59.1   59.0 
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Everyting in two calls:

```
data_runs_df <-
  map(data_runs_list, ~ map(.x, bind_rows, .id = "perc") %>% 
        bind_rows(.id = "target")) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "run")

data_info <- data_runs_df %>% 
  gather(mse, value, mse_1, mse_2) %>% 
  mutate(mse = str_c("r", mse), 
         target = str_remove(target, "mse_")) %>% 
  group_by(run, target, perc, mse) %>% 
  summarize(min = min(sqrt(value)), 
            max = max(sqrt(value)), 
            median = median(sqrt(value))) %>% 
  gather(measure, value, min, max, median) %>% 
  spread(mse, value)
```

If you insist on the list-format you were using, you can do:

```
data_info_list <- map(c("A", "B"), function(x) filter(data_info, target == x))
names(data_info_list) <- c("A", "B")
```

**Data**

```
mse_samp1 <- 
  list("mse_A" = list("P10" = data.frame(number = 1:3, mse_1 = c(2.5, 4.6, 7.8), mse_2 = c(6.7, 8.9, 4.1)), 
                      "P30" = data.frame(number = 1:3, mse_1 = c(22.5, 74.6, 97.8), mse_2 = c(56.7, 78.9, 14.1))),
       "mse_B" = list("P10" = data.frame(number = 1:3, mse_1 = c(122.5, 124.6, 127.8), mse_2 = c(126.7, 128.9, 124.1)), 
                      "P30" = data.frame(number = 1:3, mse_1 = c(3422.5, 3474.6, 3497.8), mse_2 = c(3456.7, 3478.9, 3414.1))))

mse_samp2 <- 
  list("mse_A" = list("P70" = data.frame(number = 1:3, mse_1 = c(22.2, 77.6, 97.8), mse_2 = c(26.7, 78.9, 17.1)),
                      "P80" = data.frame(number = 1:3, mse_1 = c(1022.2, 3077.6, 9097.8), mse_2 = c(7626.7, 2278.9, 7317.1))),
       "mse_B" = list("P70" = data.frame(number = 1:3, mse_1 = c(3722.2, 3777.6, 3797.8), mse_2 = c(3726.7, 3778.9, 3717.1)),
                      "P80" = data.frame(number = 1:3, mse_1 = c(1022.2, 3077.6, 9097.8), mse_2 = c(7626.7, 2278.9, 7317.1))))

data_runs_list <- list(run1 = mse_samp1, run2 = mse_samp2)
```